# Find relative points on plane after rotation in Aframe

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am using Aframe to generate a plane in a scene. I would like to find the center points on the 4 sides of the plane given an xyz rotation of the plane.

Are there any equations or relevant functions in Threejs or Aframe I can use to get the xyz coordinates of each corner?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach

1. Store the original corner coordinates

Multiple ways to do this, in this case we can just read the vertices:

```
const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh") 
// _vertices is a Float32Array containing the coords
const _vertices = mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
```

2. Transform the coordinates

We can get the "current" vertex coordinate by applying the transform matrix to the original coordinate:

```
const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
const mtx = mesh.worldMatrix;
const vec = new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z);
vec.applyMatrix4(mtx);
// now vec contains the x,y,z coordinates transformed by the matrix.
```

For example:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("track-position", {
    init: function() {
      // vector for later calculations
      this.tmpV = new THREE.Vector3();
      // <p> element to print output
      this.textEl = document.querySelector("p")
    },
    tick: function() {
      const mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh") // grab the mesh
      // grab the vertices from the buffer geometry
      const verticesArr = mesh.geometry.attributes.position.array;
      // get the world transform matrix
      const mtx = mesh.matrixWorld;

      var text = "vertices:<br>"
      for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // fill the vector from the vertices array
        this.tmpV.fromArray(verticesArr, i * 3);
        // apply the transform matrix to the vector
        this.tmpV.applyMatrix4(mtx)

        // use the data
        text += "x: " + this.tmpV.x.toFixed(2) + " , y: " + this.tmpV.y.toFixed(2) + " , z: " + this.tmpV.z.toFixed(2) + "<br>"
      }
      this.textEl.innerHTML = text;

    }
  })
</script>
<p style="position: fixed; z-index: 99">
  Hi
</p>
<a-scene>
  <a-plane position="0 0 -4" rotation="45 0 0" track-position width="4" height="4" color="#7BC8A4" material="side: double" animation="property: rotation; to: 405 0 0; loop: true; easing: linear; dur: 5000"></a-plane>
</a-scene>
```